# How can I create and use views using EF6 Code First?

Tags: stored-procedures, ef-code-first, view

Is there actually any official strategy for creating and using views with EF6.1 Code First? I can reverse the database into Code First and get tables not views. I can import the database into Model First and get views and then do Generate DB from Model and my edmx is modified and the views are converted to tables. MSFT seems to have all but abandoned Model First, and the new Update 2 seems to have reverse engineering for Code First so I feel forced to convert to Code First but has the EF team given support for any reasonable approach to using views or stored Procedures in Code First? After all CF is supposed to create the DB but what - are you no longer supposed to use either of these SQL Server features in a .NET EF application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters you can use views and stored procedures that are already created in the database. For views you don't have to do any mapping if you create a code like this:

```
public TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> AdminUsers { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a view in the database named dbo.AdminUsers and it can be mapped to the class User (contains all required properties with the same name as the property).

For stored procedures you can use the SqlQuery function either through the Database property of the DbContext such as:

```
var userActivityReport = context.Database.SqlQuery<UserActivityReport>(
    "dbo.GetUserActivityReport @p0, @p1", startDate, endDate);
```

Or through the SqlQuery function of the DbSet class:

```
var newUsers = context.Users.SqlQuery("dbo.GetNewUsers @p0", count);
```

If you want to create, modify or delete views and stored procedures via Entity Framework you can either use custom migration operations see http://dolinkamark.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/creating-a-custom-migration-operation-in-entity-framework/

For event better integration you can use the Public mapping API with a library provided by a community member: https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/

Comment: Wow. Thanks. All the reading I did I saw no info on just using the view like that.