# how to add a table manually to entity framework model database first

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql

Im using PostgreSQL and entity framework,those work with PostgreSQL and .net know how nightmare it is when you want to add a view or table,i do it thought XML,and takes half an hour to add a view manually,is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using code first or db first? You can't create automatically a view with EF, you need a custom migration operation or add the raw query in a migration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231390/how-can-i-create-and-use-views-using-ef6-code-first

Comment: @Zysce its database first

Comment: Did you checked this website? http://www.npgsql.org

Comment: @Zysce not really,im looking for a way to map a table with my entity manually using database first approach